# Does minecraft constantly read and write the anvil files?

Tags: minecraft

I read about how minecraft stores the chunk and region data. Whitch effectively is a kind of a compressed archive format. But it rose a question in my head.

Does minecraft constantly read and write these anvil files while working? Like whenever a new chunk is generated, it then gets added to the anvil file immediately. And when user returns to some old chunk that has already been generated before, then it is read from the anvil file.

I understand how the anvil file and format is setup and all that, but i just dont fully understand how it is actually used in practise, in real time while the game is running.